# nil pointer in Pascal

Tags: pointers, pascal, behavior

I have a problem understanding the behavior of pointers set to nil in Pascal. I am using turbo  pascal 7.0.
**It seems that when I set two pointers head,tail to nil...they always seem to point to the same value in the future**, even if they are assigned to **different** values.

In the code below, when I've commented out the problem area, and get the expected results.

When I remove comments from this pair of lines
head:=nil;
tail:=nil;

The 'head' pointer always seems to take the value given to the 'tail' pointer when de-referenced. Any insight provided will be appreciated.

```
    program LinkedListTest;
type
    ListNodePtr = ^ListNode;
    ListNode = record
        key,cycleLength: integer;
        NodePtr: ListNodePtr;
    end;

{
We have just defined the node of a linked list.
Next we declare our head which is the pointer to the first node
and the tail which points to the last node.
The head helps us find our first node in the list
the tail helps us to keep track of the last node in the list.
Both are simple pointers to a node (in our case ListNodePtr).
}

var
head,tail : ListNodePtr;
node1,node2,node3,node4: ListNode;
count: integer;

{Init the linked list}

procedure InitLinkedList;
Begin
new(head);
new(tail);

(*   **Remove comments from this code to see problems in final output**
head:=nil;
tail:=nil;
*)
node1.key:=10;

new(node1.NodePtr);
node1.NodePtr:=nil;
head^:=node1;
tail^:=node1;
writeln('head key is now: ',head^.key);



node2.key:=20;
new(node2.NodePtr);
node2.NodePtr:=nil;




head^.NodePtr^:=node2;



tail^:=node2;

writeln('head key is now: ',head^.key);
writeln('tail key is now: ',tail^.key);
writeln('node1 key is now: ',node1.key);
writeln('node2 key is now: ',node2.key);
readln;
end;

begin

InitLinkedList;

end
.
```

Comment: If your 'updated solution' still has erros then describe them. Otherwise post it as a self-answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen this reply. I'll await further responses then do what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There are several strange things.

You load data into allocate a record on the stack (node1), which will be gone on procedure exit, and then deep copy its contents (not references/pointers) into the records allocated to head and tail (using new).

```
       head^:=node1;
       tail^:=node1;
```

At that point you have three copies of node1's content, node1, head^ and tail^

With node2 you make the same mistake. (  head^.NodePtr^:=node2)

You can assign the points by simply assigning them, e.g.

```
     head:=tail;
```

and access fields directly too

```
       head^.field:=something
```

if head points to something sane.

This construct:

```
  new(node1.NodePtr);
  node1.NodePtr:=nil;
```

is essentially a memory leak. You allocate space for a record to nodeptr, but then immediately assign NIL to it, leaving no reference to the just allocated record.

HINT: work out your algorithm on paper with boxes (to signify records) and arrows (to signify pointers) first.

Comment: Thank you for this in depth reply. There is a lot going on that I was not aware of. I will work out the exact details of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Changes made: no more procedure calls

Comment: You are still assigning records on the stack to pointers. In the case of dynamic datastructures that is wrong, because they will be invalid on function exit.

Comment: I'm now creating new nodes using new(tempPtr) and using dereferencing to assign values. When I use new() I think this will reserve memory from the heap thus solving the problems of procedure calls using memory from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

**Revision 1- Removed local variables Node1 and Node2**

**Set tail 'next node' pointer to nil**

**check that head points to tail for 2 nodes in the list**

**UPDATED SOLUTION BASED ON ANSWERS**

```
program LinkedListTest;
type
    ListNodePtr = ^ListNode;
    ListNode = record
        key,cycleLength: integer;
        NodePtr: ListNodePtr;
    end;


var
head,tail,tempPtr : ListNodePtr;
count: integer;
pointerIsNil: boolean;
{Init the linked list}


begin

new(head);
new(tail);
new(tempPtr);
tempPtr^.key:=10;
head:=tempPtr;
tail:=tempPtr;
tail^.NodePtr:=nil;
writeln('head key is now: ',head^.key);
writeln('tail key is now: ',tail^.key);
pointerIsNil:=head^.NodePtr = nil;
writeln('Is heads node ptr nil? Answer is: ',pointerIsNil);
new(tempPtr);
tempPtr^.key:=20;
head^.Nodeptr:=tempPtr;
tail:=tempPtr;
writeln('head key is now: ',head^.key);
writeln('tail key is now: ',tail^.key);

pointerIsNil:=head^.NodePtr = nil;
writeln('Is heads node ptr nil? Answer is: ',pointerIsNil);
writeln('Making sure head is linked to the tail ',head^.NodePtr^.key);


readln;


end
.
```